# firebase flutter push notificaiton

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send push notification from my php application to my flutter apps via Firebase messaging service. while I start the emulator it receives a token from firebase, then i copy that token and can send message. But I want to store that token to my mysql database once i receive the token. I have 2 scenario. For the first time if user install the apps, i'll insert the token to my database so that i can send message using that token. Now I am confused how to update that token every time the user login(not inserting new token again and again to database).

```
  void setupNotification() async{
    _firebaseMessaging.
    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token){
      //insert the token to user database
      saveToken(token); 
    });

    Stream<String> fcmStream = _firebaseMessaging.onTokenRefresh;
    fcmStream.listen((token) {
      //always update the user database with new token
      saveToken(token); 
    });
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
        onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async{
          print("message while app is open: $message");
        },
        onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async{
          print("message: $message");
        },
        onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async{
          print("message: $message");
        }
    );
  }
```

I mean **how to identify that the token is new or old**(updated) ?

Comment: you can simply compare your tokens. If the new token and the old tokens are different then you'll update your token otherwise tokens will not be changed

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Locally stored json file in your app using path_provider plugin.This file will get initialized everytime user opens the app and will contain a user Model containing token of user.On the very first page of the app in initState check if the user is not null.
IF NULL:
Get fcm token and store it in database.After storing it in database write the token in your Locally stored file.
ELSE:
Do nothing

Next time when same user opens the app again in initstate it will check if user is not null.This time it will not add a new token in database as our code to insert token into database won't execute.

Example:
We will store user as follows.

```
class User {
  String token;
  String platform;

  User({
    this.token = '',
    this.platform = '',
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson()  {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['token'] = this.token;
    data['platform'] = this.platform;
    return data;
  }

  User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json): this(
    platform: json["platform"],
    token: json["token"],
  );
}
```

Local Data file:

```
class LocalData {
  static User _user;

  static User get user => _user;

  /// Flag for Authentication.
  static bool get isTokenAdded=> _user != null;




  static loadData() async {
    final file = File((await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path + '/data.json');

    try {
      final data = jsonDecode(await file.readAsString());

      _user = User.fromJson(data['user']);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  static writeData() async {
    final file = File((await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path + '/data.json');

    await file.writeAsString(jsonEncode({
      'user': _user?.toJson(),
    }));
  }



  static void addToken(User user) {

    LocalData._user = user;
    writeData();
  }

  static void removeToken() {
    LocalData._user = null;
    writeData();
  }

}
```

App's main function:

```
void main() async {
  /// Load Local Data.
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await LocalData.loadData();

  runApp(YourApp());
}
```

Now in initState of your apps first page you can check if token is already added in database by

```
if(LocalData.isTokenAdded()){
     //do nothing
}else{
//get token and insert it into database then write it in file: 
LocalData.user.token = token;
LocalData.writeData();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more codes i am struggling with FCM? Do i need to define onresume, onmessge and other in main.dart file or anywhere in project. My notifications are not visible in app when it is running or in background. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65166526/flutter-fcm-fatal-failed-to-find-callback